# which causal diagram is correct?

Tags: causality

In causality, there is the ‘kidney stone’ study which is quite famous, which poses the next causal diagram:
[image]

But, now in the talk from the Royal stats societe https://youtu.be/TFWgC5J6iDw, this causal diagram is posed, for a similar case:
[image]

Which diagram is the correct one? (I assume the second one is wrong…)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the two diagrams are designed to answer different causal questions. Keep in mind where causal diagrams come from: your own imagination! You have a causal question you want to ask, and you draw the diagram to answer it.

The first diagram is asking about the effects of kidney stone size on recovery. The second diagram is asking about the closeness-to-the-hospital effect on recovery. They are different questions.

Now, typically in most causal diagrams, you have exogenous variables. You could likely think of kidney stone size as an exogenous variable for the second diagram, and closeness-to-hospital as an exogenous variable in the first diagram.